Core Data and NSSortDescriptor: Combining Values During Sort
Is it possible to apply a NSSortDescriptor that investigates two (or more!) keys while fetching from Core Data?
Currently we fetch the objects and sort them in memory by investigating two values. We combine those two values with a computed property, just like in the following imagined example:
struct ObjectWithDates {

  var date1: Date
  var date2: Date

  var dateForSorting: Date {
    [date1, date2].max()
  }
}

...Example usage...

NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateForSorting", ascending: false)


Is it possible to perform effectively this during the Core Data fetch? I had tried using a derived attribute upon the Core Data entity, but could not get the system to recognize the 'max' function. Is there something else to try, maybe programattically with NSExpression? Thank you!

I am pretty sure you can't do something like this for your sort descriptors

NSFetchRequest accepts array of sort descriptors. What is the problem?

@Cy-4AH The combined sort descriptors are applied serially. That's great if you want to sort by one criterium, then by another criterium. However, we want to sort by a single criterium determined by combining values. Consider sorting by two dates... if done serially, we'd sort by the first date, and then if there are objects with identical date values we'd sort by the second date. Whereas we want to sort by the latest of those two dates ([date1, date2].max()).

No, it's not possible. You'll have to persist the dateForSorting and update it as date1 and date2 are modified.
It's a popular idea though ;)

Set NSSortDescriptor for CoreData using a calculated field
Sorting NSFetchedResultsController by Swift Computed Property on NSManagedObjectSubclass
Sorting on 'transient' fields with NSFetchedresultController
What is the fastest way to sort a lot of locations on distance?

The reason you can’t is that the comparisons/predicate checks are happening “behind” Core Data, inside the opaque persistent store. The code you’re proposing would run on the application side, after the objects have been fetched and instantiated. If you can’t express the predicate in SQLite, then you won’t be able to come up with an equivalent predicate in Core Data.

Instead of adding yet another answer, close the question as duplicate please.
